# Javascript variable to PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
    var selVal = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: 'remove_task.php', //This is the current doc
        data: ({sel: selVal}),
        success: function(data){
            //alert(selVal);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });        
});
});
```

My PHP function in remove_task.php:

```
function remove_selected_task()
{
  $task_to_remove = $_POST['sel'];
  echo $task_to_remove;
}
if (isset($_POST['remsubmit']))
{
  remove_selected_task();
}
```

Not able to pass this successfully. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the parentheses around `({sel: selVal})`?

Comment: How is it not successful? Is it empty on the PHP side? Unset? Wrong data? Have you checked that `selVal` (`$(this).val()`) has the desired value on the JS side?

Comment: We need more information.  When is `remove_selected_task` called?  Is the ajax request occurring successfully?  Any errors on the PHP or JavaScript side?

Comment: what's pointed by jszobody should solve the problem : simply remove the parenthesis

Comment: Have you attempted to log/debug this in your browser developer console?

Comment: i hope in your php you are properly delegating to the `remove_selected_task` function, try a `var_dump` in your php what do you get ?

Comment: Changed that. But that did not help.

Comment: @Asenar parethensis is not a issue here, just useless. I'm quite sure OP just doesn't call the PHP function

Comment: Are you sure you can `echo $task_to_remove;` Isn't it an array?

Comment: The paenthesis did not solve the problem.

Comment: in remove_task.php, I hope you call your function , right ?

Comment: I tried alert and selVal has the right value.

Comment: in fact we have no clue about what is your problem, if it's php side or javascript. What's the error message you get (or not)

Comment: do you ever call the function in php? SHow more php code

Comment: Complete php code is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JGdnVft0rBQS7CbJr4yz-J1jm4ilc8eTJX_3H-KZgYI/edit

Comment: @Asenar my problem is I'm not able to pass a variable value from JS to PHP. JS however gets the right value into the variable. However PHP is not getting that value.

Comment: huh, looking at your PHP code, it's fairly obvious really. Your code does nothing if `remsubmit` is not set. And your JS code doesn't include `remsubmit` in the parameters list.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the $_POST variable into the function for ex:

```
remove_selected_task($_POST['sel']);

function remove_selected_task($task_to_remove)
{

  echo $task_to_remove;
}
```

Comment: The following too did not work.

function remove_selected_task($task_to_remove)
{

  echo $task_to_remove;
}


if (isset($_POST['remsubmit']))
{
remove_selected_task($_POST['sel']);
}

Comment: can you just explain what is this $_POST['remsubmit']...?

Comment: $_POST['remsubmit'] is a remove button. I select the options from checklist click the button which takes me to the php page. JS is getting the right value of the selected option. However PHP is not displaying the same.

Comment: i tried removing isset($_POST['remsubmit'] ) and i,m getting right value Check this php
<?php
function remove_selected_task($task_to_remove)
{
    echo $task_to_remove;
}
    remove_selected_task($_POST['sel']);
?>
can give provide html..?  and your are not passing any remsubmit in ajax call

Comment: your are not passing any remsubmit in ajax call and why are you checking isset($_POST['remsubmit']) in php file,as it is empty you wont get any echoed value

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying to diagnose the issue using the browser dev tools. Press F12 to get the dev tools panel, and go to the Network tab.

Now click your checkbox and watch for what happens...

- Does the network panel show the request being made to `remove_task.php`?

  If not, then there's a problem in your javascript where it registers the click event. Maybe the selector is wrong or something like that.

  If the network panel *does* show the request being made, click on it there to get more info about it, and then look at the request data and the response data.
- Does the request send the data you're expecting it to, and in the correct format?

  If not, then you'll need to debug your Javascript to see why. I can't really help with that unless I actually see the data, but you should be able to get an idea of what the problem is by what's being sent incorrectly. Maybe the checkbox value is wrong?

  If it does look right, then move on to the response.
- Does the response contain the data you expect?

  If it has a 404 response code, then your URL is incorrect. Maybe the path is wrong?

  If the response includes an error message, then you should be able to debug the PHP from that. It'll have the relevant line numbers in it, so that should be enough to get you going.

  If the response is blank, then your PHP code isn't sending anything back: Maybe a syntax error (with error suppression), or maybe the program ends before it gets to `echo` the data. Either way, further debugging in the PHP will be required.

That's about as much help as I can give, given the info you supplied in the question. I hope that's enough to get you started.

Comment: This helped me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, and next time add the full code in your question.

you check if "remsubmit" exists in your php file, but you don't send it ! This should work by modifying the line `data: ({sel: selVal})` as below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$(".checkbox").click(function(){
  var selVal = $(this).val(); 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'remove_task.php', //This is the current doc
    data: {sel: selVal, remsubmit:"1"},
    success: function(data){
        //alert(selVal);
        console.log(data);
    }
  });        
});
});
```

Comment: This is a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer. Explain what you changed and why!

Comment: and what does a direct call to your php file if you add at the first line (right after `<?php`) this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ` ?

Comment: This is the error

Notice: Undefined index: sel in /var/www/To-Do-List/remove_task.php on line 43

Comment: so you can work on that now :) . We cannot debug all your script without even having it's content !

Comment: okay I will look into it. As far I can see the value is not getting passed to PHP

Comment: I think it is, but there is probably several error in your code, and only you can fix them. Be aware about variables names, maybe you typed $POST instead of $_POST or something like this.

Comment: HI this worked. I figured out the problem. The submit button was refreshing the page. I removed the submit button and everything works. Thanks for all the support.